# How do we deduce that $\mathbb{Q}_p=\{ p^mu\mid u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}, m \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cup \{0\}$?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

We know that each element $x$ of $\mathbb{Z} \setminus{\{0\}}$ has a unique representation of the form $x=p^m u\mid m \in \mathbb{N}_0, u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}$.

$$\mathbb{Q}_p=\left \{ \frac{r}{s}: r, s \in \mathbb{Z}_p, s \neq 0 \right \}$$

From the above proposition, we can write $s$ as follows:

$$s=p^mu, m \in \mathbb{N}_0, u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{r}{s}=\frac{r}{p^mu}=\frac{ru'}{p^m(uu')}=\frac{ru'}{p^m}$$

$$ru'=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_ip^i$$

Therefore $\mathbb{Q}_p=\{ p^mu\mid u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}, m \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cup \{0\}$.

Could you exlain me how we deduce that $\mathbb{Q}_p=\{ p^mu\mid u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}, m \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cup \{0\}$?

Also, knowing that $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ is an embedding, how can we show that $\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p$ is also an embedding?

Comment: Write $r=p^ku^\prime$ in that form too. Then you have $\frac rs= p^{m-k}\frac {u^\prime}u$

Comment: But it can be that $m-k<0$.. Or am I wrong? @Mathmo123

Comment: It can be less than zero. In fact it will be $\ge0$ if and only if $\frac rs$ is a p-adic integer. Remember that non integers will have absolute value greater than 1

Comment: You're right, but it's not a problem. For the embedding of $\mathbf Q$ into $\mathbf Q_p$, it's simply that a morphism from a field into any ring is injective.

Answer (score 3):

Every nonzero element of the ring of $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ can be written in a unique way as $p^mu$, where $u$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

The field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so its nonzero elements are of the form
$$
\frac{r}{s}
$$
with $r,s\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, $r\ne0$. Then
$$
r=p^mu,\quad s=p^nv
$$
so
$$
\frac{r}{s}=\frac{p^mu}{p^nv}=p^{m-n}uv^{-1}
$$
Hence every nonzero element of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ can be written as $p^kw$, with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $w$ invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. The converse is obvious, as $\frac{1}{p}=p^{-1}\in\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ embeds in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has characteristic $0$ and is a field, so the embedding extends to an embedding of the quotient field of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: egreg Which is he converse? Do we suppose that $p^k w \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ and we want to show that it is equal to $\frac{r}{s}$ where $r,z \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ ?
$$$$
Also, how do we deduce that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has characterictic $0$ ?

Comment: @evinda The converse is $\mathbb{Q}_p\supseteq\{ p^mu\mid u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}, m \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cup \{0\}$, which is obvious. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ embeds in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ the characteristic is obviously $0$.